# Check for missing gems and pending migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

If I try to run `rails server` or `rails console` and there are uninstalled dependencies or pending migrations, I will get an error message informing me about this.

Is there any similar Rails command that can be run for doing this check, without booting server or console?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much you'll have to gain from checking, since you can just run the actual commands and it'll tell you the same information and take pretty much the same amount of time:

```
alias rs='bundle && rake db:migrate && rails s'
```

One thing you could do is integrate the [`hookup` gem](https://github.com/tpope/hookup). It basically manages this annoyance for you whenever you change branches, automatically running `bundle` and `rake db:migrate`. It also, conveniently, rolls back migrations that are not on the branch you're changing to, which can be a pain, too. It does add a bit of a performance penalty, though, especially on larger projects.

```
gem install hookup
cd yourproject
hookup install
```

Answer (score 0):

For gems it's easy enough to just run:

```
bundle check
```

For db this will show you if any migrations are pending with a "down" status:

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

or in rails 5 or higher

```
rails db:migrate:status #rails 5+
```